# What is the simplest way to describe a mathematical space?

Tags: general-relativity, noneuclidean-geometry

As a complete noob in mathematics, I was wondering, what is the simplest way to describe a (preferably 2-dimensional, becuase it will be simpler) non-euclidean space in mathematics.

For example in general relativity spacetime is a 4 dimensional non-euclidean space. And I am guessing it has some kind of a function that depends on the mass in it's surrounding and sort of curves the space accordingly.

But that is quite advanced stuff. What would be the simplest example, of a mathematical space as a function of some variable. (If I am making sense).

**Note:** I know upto basic calculus.

Comment: One such two-dimensional space is the real projective plane. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space

Comment: You might also find the Mobius band, and Klein bottle interesting. They demonstrate a phenomenon known as non-orientability. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip
and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle
The latter surface cannot be drawn without self-intersection in 3D space (but it can in 4D).

Comment: I think what you're specifically interested in is non-euclidean geometry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Euclidean_geometry

Comment: Spherical geometry is probably the gentlest introduction to a non-Euclidean space. The surface of a sphere is two-dimensional, and "straight lines" here are called *great circles.* They are the intersection of the sphere with a plane through the sphere's center; "equatorial," if you will. Line segments are just connected pieces of great circles. Hyperbolic planes are harder to think about; it's probably easiest to write down a funny "distance function" on a circle, to define them, but it's not exactly intuitive (or hands on) to me, at least.

Answer (score 0):

The study of spaces in this way sounds more like Topology. This has a lot to do with the fundamental definition of distance.

Many different types of spaces metric spaces are one powerful way of creating them. 
[image: many different spaces]

Any function that meets the requirements can be stated to be a distance and give rise to different spaces of which some are equal.

1. The distance from x to y is the distance from y to x
2. The distance from x to y is greater than 0 and equal to 0 iff x = y
3. The distance from x to y plus the distance from y to z is greater than the distance from x to z.

anything that follows those rules gives a definition of distance and hence defines a space.

A simple example is the taxi cab metric where you can only "travel" on unit grids. so the distance between (a,b) and (c,d) = abs(a-c)+abs(b-d). Think about what a circle would look like in this space.

It looks like a diamond!

Comment: How can I "draw" a function on it? I mean I know that the equation of a circle of radius r is $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. How can I use the distance formula you gave to "draw" or "calculate" or "imagine" a circle?

Comment: Imagine what the loci of points equidistant to a point is.

Comment: Okay, that is quite interesting. Thank you. But I had something else in mind. Maybe it is non sensical: consider the function $f(x) = e^(rx)$ where r can be considered sort of like a "curving constant". I thought spaces in mathematics would be something like this. Am I wrong? Or did I interpret your answer wrongly? Or maybe spaces other than the metric space accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: That sounds like a polar plot and you could certainly define distance between (a,b) and (c,d) to be e^abs(a-c),e^abs(d-b) and it will define a space.

Comment: Space is a loosely defined concept that kind of gets defined in topology. like is this space connected? or can i fold this space into that one without cusp? and other questions concerning the openness of the space. having a metric isnt the only way to define such a space but it is one of the easiest.